# Getting stack frames on Windows for C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I am trying to obtain stack trace and symbol information in a C++ program. I am following the approach described in this article: http://code-freeze.blogspot.com/2012/01/generating-stack-traces-from-c.html The basic idea is to use DbgHelp library, use StackWalk64 to get the address of the stack frames.

In my program, the main program loads other dlls and calls functions in the dlls. The approach works when I try to print_stack() (assuming I put the implementation in a function with name print_stack) in the main program. But if I try to call print_stack() from a dll, the result does not make sense. I tried to put two print_stack() function calls in two places on one call chain. Ideally part of printed stack frame addresses should be the same, but it is not the case. So I suspect the StackWalk64 does not obtain correct stack frame addresses.

Anyone saw such a problem before?

Is there anyway to know the correct stack frame address? Visual Studio debugger does not give address information. WinDbg is very very slow...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VS, but in WinDBG you can print a callstack with addresses by the kv command, or by enabling addresses in the callstack window. WinDbg is a lot faster if you start it up with the -snul option (or uncheck the Resolve Unqualified Symbols under the Debug menu)